# How can I add textview dynamically from arraylist?

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible add textView in a relative layout dynamically, taking the information from an arraylist? I'll explain. For example I have a arralist with five words that I get from a database. I would then create 5 different textView in its layout.
I can not use a listview because it is the user to choose the poszione of these TextView.

This is the code I was working, so I was able to create more TextView, but not from the array list. I also need to give different values ​​for the top margin at each TextView!

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.sundayRelativeLayout);
    TextView iv;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

    

    float d = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    iv = new TextView(this);
    iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    int marginTopDip = 180; // margin in dips
    int marginHeightDips = 60; // margin in dips

    int height = (int)(marginHeightDips * d);
    int margintop = (int)(marginTopDip * d);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(500, height);
    params.topMargin = margintop;
    rl.addView(iv, params);



    iv = new TextView(this);
    iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 40);
    params.topMargin = 900;
    rl.addView(iv, params);
```

Comment: you can programatically create TextView and position them using `LayoutParams`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create like this

```
ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

if your list size is 5

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setText(""+list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: thanks! tthis is work! but how do I get my TextView in different margin top with each other?

Comment: LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourTextView.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: This is correct, but I need to also receive in this case information from an array list, so that they are associated with texview.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
 int variable=list.get(i);
} you can get the data from arraylist like this

Answer (score 0):

```
final int N = 10; // total number of textviews to add

final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // create a new textview
    final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);

    // set some properties of rowTextView or something
    rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);

    // add the textview to the linearlayout
    myLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);

    // save a reference to the textview for later
    myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can add textview to the relative layout like this.

```
RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
       TextView textView = new TextView(this);
       textView1.setText("A"+i);
       textView1.setId(i);
       container.addView(textView);
       params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,i);      
    }
```